# How to make my factorial function faster and efficient?

Tags: python, function, factorial

I made factorial calculating function using list

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))

def num2list(num):
    first = [int(i) for i in str(num)]
    return first

def multiplylists(x, y):
    listx = x
    listy = y
    value=0
    for n in range(len(listx)):
        for m in range(len(listy)):
            prod = listx[n]*listy[m]
            power=10**((len(listx)-n-1)+(len(listy)-m-1))
            value+=prod*power
    return(num2list(value))

def factorial(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return [1]

    return multiplylists(factorial(n-1), num2list(n))

print("the factorial of",n,"is",factorial(n))
```

this is college project and i think professor's intention is making a faster, efficient factorial function using list like 1000!

but my code is slow and when number > 997

i got error like this

```
Enter a number: 1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "part2.py", line 24, in <module>
    print("the factorial of",n,"is",factorial(n))
  File "part2.py", line 22, in factorial
    return multiplylists(factorial(n-1), num2list(n))
  File "part2.py", line 22, in factorial
    return multiplylists(factorial(n-1), num2list(n))
  File "part2.py", line 22, in factorial
    return multiplylists(factorial(n-1), num2list(n))
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
  File "part2.py", line 19, in factorial
    if n <= 1:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

i do not know why my code error when number > 997

Comment: Python has a (configurable) limit on how large the call stack can grow; it is most commonly exceeded by recursive functions. That's one reason why iteration is preferred over recursion in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the maximum recursion depth, you will not be able to compute factorials greater than 1000 (actually smaller because some stack levels are already used by other calling functions)

So you need to implement an iterative approach.  To produce numbers expressed as digits in a list, it will be easier to store the digits in reverse order so that the index of a digit corresponds to the power of 10 it is multiplied by.  You can reverse the list for human readability when printing or when returning the result.

With this digit storage strategy the multiplication logic can be more straightforward.  You should also implemented it without "cheating" with Python's infinite size integers (e.g. `10**((len(listx)-n-1)+(len(listy)-m-1)`):

```
def toDigits(n):
    result = []
    while n:
        n,d = divmod(n,10)
        result.append(d)
    return result or [0]

def multDigits(A,B):
    result = [0]
    for i,a in enumerate(A):
        for j,b in enumerate(B):
            p10,carry = i+j,a*b 
            while carry:
                if p10 >= len(result): result.append(0); continue
                carry,result[p10] = divmod(carry+result[p10],10)
                p10 += 1
    return result

def factorial(N):
    result = [1]
    for n in range(2,N+1):
        result = multDigits(result,toDigits(n))
    return result[::-1]
```

output:

```
print(factorial(1000))

[4, 0, 2, 3, 8, 7, 2, 6, 0, 0, 7, 7, 0, 9, 3, 7, 7, 3, 5, ...


# proof that it works:

from math import factorial
digits = [ int(d) for d in str(factorial(1000)) ]
print(digits)

[4, 0, 2, 3, 8, 7, 2, 6, 0, 0, 7, 7, 0, 9, 3, 7, 7, 3, 5, ...
```

Comment: I appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The `sys` module in Python provides a function called `setrecursionlimit()` to modify the recursion limit in Python. It takes one parameter, the value of the new recursion limit.

```
import sys 

sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6) 
def fact(n):  
    if(n == 0): 
        return 1 
    return n * fact(n - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply make it iterative to run in O(n).

```
n = 500
facts = [1]*(n+1)
for i in range(1,n+1):
   facts[i] = facts[i-1]*(i)

print(facts[n])
```

Comment: `n` = maximum factorial you want to calculate. After running the loop, the array stores the factorials sequentially. facts[3] = 3!, facts[7] = 7! and so on.

Comment: Thanks! i appreciate for your help

Answer (score -2):

```
def fact(n):
if n==0:
    return 1
else:
    return (n * fact(n-1))


 x=fact(1000)
print(x)
```

Comment: Please don't just paste code - explain why it works and how it solves the problem. Also, your code isn't indented properly.

Comment: This has the same issue as the original code, just in shorter form. If `n` is too large, you will exceed the allowable stack size.